# Converts digits to words in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel-5

I am trying to convert digits to words in laravel 5.2 using **Terbilang**.
 I first run the below CLI

```
composer require riskihajar/terbilang
```

and then added Providers & Aliases to config file:

```
Riskihajar\Terbilang\TerbilangServiceProvider::class,
'Terbilang' => Riskihajar\Terbilang\Facades\Terbilang::class,
```

then I used **Terbilang::make(1000);** to the controller and I got the following error

> FatalThrowableError in PdfController.php line 78: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Terbilang' not found.

Is there anything that Imissed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to add the following in your controller above the class declaration.

```
use Terbilang;
```